# Count reactions to a message after certain time has passed

Tags: discord.js

So I made a bot that has a vote command, where you ask it to say a votable thing and people can only react with tick, cross or N/A in discord.js

What I need to make work now, is a response (either by command or automated over-time, but preferably automated over the time period of 24hrs).

So far, I've tried many different methods and looked all over the Discord.js Docs, but nothing has quite worked out at all. Here's how the code ended up, although it doesn't work:

```
var textToEcho = args.join(" ");
Client.channels.cache.get('channel ID').send(textToEcho).then(async m => {
                await m.react('✅');
                await m.react('❎');
                await m.react('801426534341541919');
            });
message.channel.fetchMessage(textToEcho).then(msg => {
    let downVoteCollection = msg.reactions.filter(rx => rx.emoji.name == '✅');
    console.log(downVoteCollection.first().count);
}).catch(console.error);
```

*Note*: This **ONLY** checks for the tick response.

Comment: Where have you defined textToEcho & have you got any errors?

Comment: textToEcho is defined just before this block of code (when sending the message people vote on), there are only errors when it attempts to count the reactions

Comment: Can you show what testToEcho is and the errors you are receiving are in your question. This will help us provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to get all of the reactions directly after the message has been sent, this will only return the bots reactions, if any at all.
To accurately get the reactions after a certain about of time you'll have to add a `.setTimeout(...)` function.

```js
var textToEcho = args.join(" ");
Client.channels.cache.get('channel ID').send(textToEcho).then(async m => {
    await m.react('✅');
    await m.react('❎');
    await m.react('801426534341541919');
});
setTimeout(() => {
    message.channel.messages.fetch(message.id).then(msg => {
        let downVoteCollection = msg.reactions.filter(rx => rx.emoji.name == '✅'); // Filter the reactions
        msg.author.send(`You have received **${downVoteCollection.first().count}** votes on your latest poll!`); // Sends the poll owner how many votes they recieved
    }).catch(console.error);
}, 86400000); // This will wait 24 hours after the message has been sent to count reactions
```

Comment: ok, but I need this to send the amount of reactions to a user, not just count them up in the console

Comment: @CKStudios2018 View my latest edit this should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I may have just lost two votes by restarting the bot with the new code, but a little sacrifice goes a long way. - That aside, thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: wait, this doesn't work, it only allows sending of one emoji now.
Also, completely crashes the bot. `TypeError: message.channel.fetchMessage is not a function`

Comment: The bot will not count the votes if you restart the bot within the 24 hours.

Comment: I know the bot shouldn't count if the bot is restarted, and fair enough too, but it doesn't work at all now... every vote just crashes it

Comment: @CKStudios2018 Check the latest edit - if that doesn't suit your needs please post a new question as this is getting off-topic.